# flex Property ignored

Tags: apache-flex, twitter, properties

I'm trying to get an itemrenderer to display the text from a tweet, and (if there is one) the uploaded image. Text displays fine, but no matter what I do, the image doesn't show. Could it be that because I'm refering to a property that does not always exist, in this case "data.entities.media.creative.media_url" (it only exists if there is an image uploaded with the tweet) that the itemrenderer just ignores the property for all tweets?

Here's my code:

```
        [Bindable(event="dataChange")]
        public function get data():Object
        {
            return _data;
        }
        public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            _data = value;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("dataChange"));
            }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:Label text="{data.text}"
         width="100%"
         styleName="tweetlist"/>
<s:Image id="tweetImage" source="{data.entities.media.creative.media_url}"/>
```

I am quite new to Flex, and so far I managed to get things working by pasting code together from different sources. So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are binding to a deeply nested property: `data.entities.media.creative.media_url`. If you want the binding to work properly, you must make sure that each and every property on that path is made Bindable.

Concretely:

- `data` must be Bindable on the ItemRenderer; it is by default when you extend `ItemRenderer`, so I would remove your custom Bindable declaration and event dispatching (or even remove the `data` getter/setter override altogether)
- the `entities` property of the data instance must be declared Bindable
- the `media` property of the entities instance must be declared Bindable
- and so forth all the way to the `media_url` property

However it is not considered good coding practice (in general, not just in Flex) to access deeply nested properties like that, so I would advise you to encapsulate the property that you need so that you can bind to it like this:

```
<s:Image id="tweetImage" source="{data.media_url}" />
```

This will not only be better from a "clean code" point of view, but also for performance if you have a lot of items in the List. (Because the number of bindings will descrease by factor 5)

An alternative solution is to not use data binding and simply set `tweetImage`'s `source` property:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
    super.data = value;
    tweetImage.source = data.entities.media.creative.media_url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, specialy for the effort to teach something to a newbie. Unfortunatly it didn't work. I cannot change the way the properties are being defined; this comes from twitter's api. When i change the value in "data.users.profile_image_url" the images are being displayed (every tweet has this property) so it can't be the code, it must have something to do with the propertychain or the fact that not all tweets have this property at all.

Comment: @user1482027 I don't know the Twitter API, but I should tell you that bindings swallow some errors. That means that if an error occurs inside a data binding, you won't notice; simply nothing will be displayed. If you try the alternative solution though errors should be thrown if there are any. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and inspecting what is actually there in that `data` instance?

Comment: When I look in the network monitor to see what is comming back I can see the structure, and the propertychain for the first tweet contains "data.entities.media.creative.media_url" because there is an image. The other tweets do not have the "media_url" propperty. When I try the alternative I get: Error #1069: Property media not found on valueObjects.Entities and there is no default value. I have not set a breakpoint yet; first have to figure out what that is (which I will do).

Comment: @user1482027 Are you sure `entities` is not a list or an Array? Because Flash is telling you that `entities` does not have a property called `media`. And because the name is a plural, I would assume this is a collection of objects of some kind.

Comment: That is exactly my problem; when the app runs, it gets 20 tweets, and only one tweet has an image in "media_url". So, for the other 19 tweets "....media.creative.media_url" does not exist. Odly enough, for that one tweet with the image, the image doesn't get displayed either.

Comment: @user1482027 If you haven't figured out how breakpoints work yet, try tracing `data.entities.hasOwnProperty('media')` to make sure that one item really has a `media` property. Don't forget to comment out the `tweetImage.source = ...` line so the program can keep running.